# ASP.Net Print GridView

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview, webforms

I am working on an ASP.Net Web Forms application. One page in particular displays a GridView which lists several rows of data. The GridView is styled using the built in formatting which you can choose within Visual Studio. However, I need to create a print friendly version of this webpage, but when I click print, the styling/ css of the GridView disappears.

Is there anyway of keeping the nice styling/ css that is visible when viewing as a webpage?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: do you mean the styling is lost in the actual print-out, or on your print-friendly page?

Comment: I mean the styling is lost when I hit print and view the print preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a print stylesheet:

```
@media print
{
    /* GridView styling here */
}
```

or link to a stylesheet specifically for print purposes:

```
<!--These styles styles are only for screens as set by the media value-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" media="screen">

<!--These styles styles are only for print as set by the media value-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" media="print">
```

Source: [CSS Print Style Sheets - Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773044/css-print-style-sheets-examples)

Answer (score 1):

A while back I had a real problem with .net webforms insisting on adding style, border, spacing, padding attributes to the tables produced by Gridviews.

I used javascript (using jQuery) to remove them, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
$('table').filter(function (index) {  
    $(this).removeAttr("style");  
    $(this).removeAttr("rules");  
    $(this).removeAttr("border");  
    $(this).removeAttr("cellspacing");  
    $(this).removeAttr("cellpadding");  
});  
});
```

This allowed my css (specified in the 'CssClass' attribute of the gridview) to take full control.

Perhaps this might be of some help in your case.