# What is the purpose of Print device layout in Sitecore (or How do I use it properly)?

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

I have created a print button in my application that opens a new window that goes to print device layout  by appending the current url with QueryString of Print device(?p=1 in my case) and onload it calls window.print() function. But this is useless because all the data user has entered will be lost when it opens a new window containing print device layout of the current page.

I can't think of a way by which I can use the print device layout and pre-populate the page with data user has entered. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The point of the Print Device to be able to have a different set of Presentation components for display or print. Sometimes it is sufficient (and easier) to just use a print stylesheet, which hides/restyles certain elements: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12773239/661447

Comment: @jammykam Yeah that would be my last resort but does sitecore provides any other way by which I can select the sublayouts of the page that I want to print by going through the sublayouts I have selected for print device for a specific item in presentation?

Comment: No, there isn't another way that I know of. Obviously Devices works fine for non-form pages, or forms that have been posted and a confirmation page is shown (no input boxes, just text). An alternative would be to use Rendering Parameters to set on each control, which could add a `.print` or `.do-not-print` class to then be used by the print stylesheet.

Comment: @jammykam I looked it up and I guess we can't make use of the print device layout in my case. Please enter the contents of your comment in the answer. I will mark this thread as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of the Print Device to be able to have a different set of Presentation components for display or print. Sometimes it is sufficient (and easier) to just use a print stylesheet, which hides/restyles certain elements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12773239/19112

Obviously Devices works fine for non-form pages, or forms that have been posted and a confirmation page is shown (no input boxes, just text).

An alternative would be to use Rendering Parameters to set on each control, which could add a `.print` or `.do-not-print` class to then be used by the print stylesheet. You would then have to set the appropriate styles in the stylesheet to hide those elements. Note however that you cannot style the iframe content from the parent, you must link a separate stylesheet to the iframe src page if you want to style when printing.

Answer (score 0):

You can append the user inputs to the print URL query string using javascript, for example:

```
var url = 'Current-Page-URL' + '?p=1' + '&input1=[INPUT1]'+ '&input2=[INPUT2]' etc..
```

Then in Page load event, you can set these inputs in the corresponding text/dropdown elements

Comment: I cannot do that because The form data will be in a JSP page that  I am using by having an iframe tag pointing to different JSP pages in each page.

Comment: In that case, you might need to follow @jammykam notes above by using print styles and hide/show the areas for print

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned above that device is a different set of presentation that can be used for many purpose. Early years when there weren’t responsive design, I used device to rendering different mobile device. You can use device to render rss feed or anything you want where you want to have different render set.
Another example if you have multi sites and want to rendering them differently you can use device as well.

Sitecore is very flexible that’s why I love it so much. There are always other ways to get same or similar results. From your context I don’t know what you are trying to achieve. If I want to have different set of presentation
here is some approach I will look into, Lavage rendering rules, tap into request pipeline, swap rendering controls in code, on item level specify style sheet…

If you can tell us what you are trying to achieve, I am sure someone will provide you their own solution. Then you will have more options to choose from and get the best fit to your project.
Hope this help.